# Function doesn't work properly inside an `if` statement javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, while calling a function inside an if statement.

Function that doesn't work properly is `drawRight()` with 2 arguments that draws divs, text and other elements in a loop.

When I call it like that my website is just getting crashed and it looks like css wasn't applying.

```
    <div id="right">
        <script>
            $('.leftOption').click(function() {
                if(this.id == "option1") {
                    drawRight(3,5);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

If I call it outside of the statement, everything is cool, but then I can't use statement if to call it or not. :(

```
    <div id="right">
        <script>
            $('.leftOption').click(function() {
                if(this.id == "option1") {
                }
            });
            drawRight(3,5);
        </script>
    </div>
```

drawRight() function

```
let drawRight = (fromID, toID) => {
                for(var r=fromID; r<=toID; r++) {
                    if(r % 2 != 0) {
                        //nieparzyste
                        document.write(`<div id="set${r}" class="rightOption rightOptionColor1">`);
                    } else {
                        document.write(`<div id="set${r}" class="rightOption rightOptionColor2">`);
                    }

                        document.write(`<div class="r1">`);
                                document.write(`<div class="garage">`);
                                    document.write(`<img class="garage_icon" src="../assets/images/icons/icon_garage.png"/>`);
                                    document.write(`<div id="garage_header">`);
                                            document.write(`<div class="garage_text">`);
                                                    document.write(`Garaż`);
                                            document.write(`</div>`);
                                            document.write(`<div class="garage_id">`);
                                                    document.write(`(${r})`);
                                            document.write(`</div>`);
                                    document.write(`</div>`);
                                document.write(`</div>`);
                                document.write(`<div id="button${r}" class="button">`);
                                        document.write(`<div class="button_border">`);
                                                document.write(`<div class="button_text">`);
                                                        document.write(`Wejdź`);
                                                document.write(`</div>`);
                                        document.write(`</div>`);
                                document.write(`</div>`);
                        document.write(`</div>`);

                        document.write(`<div class="r2">`);
                                document.write(`<div class="owner_header">`);
                                        document.write(`<img class="owner_icon" src="../assets/images/icons/person.png">`);
                                        document.write(`<div class="owner_text">`);
                                            document.write(`Właściciel`);
                                        document.write(`</div>`);
                                        document.write(`<div id="owner${r}" class="owner_nick info_text">`);
                                                document.write(``);
                                        document.write(`</div>`);
                                document.write(`</div>`);
                        document.write(`</div>`);

                        document.write(`<div class="r3">`);
                                document.write(`<div class="parking_header">`);
                                        document.write(`<img class="parking_icon" src="../assets/images/icons/p.png">`);
                                        document.write(`<div class="parking_text">`);
                                            document.write(`Ilość miejsc`);
                                        document.write(`</div>`);
                                        document.write(`<div id="parking${r}" class="parking_quantity info_text">`);
                                                document.write(`5`);
                                        document.write(`</div>`);
                                document.write(`</div>`);
                        document.write(`</div>`);

                        document.write(`<div class="r4">`);
                                document.write(`<div class="rIcons">`);
                                    document.write(`<img id="rOwned${r}" class="rOwned rIcon" src="../assets/images/icons/owned.png"/>`);
                                    document.write(`<img id="rShared${r}" class="rShared rIcon" src="../assets/images/icons/shared.png"/>`);
                                document.write(`</div>`);
                        document.write(`</div>`);

                    document.write(`</div>`);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should click on element has id `option1` to calling function in condition, Have you done this?

Comment: After clicking on whatever element with class `leftOption` it checks if this element has id `option1` and it works properly with other things, just this functions blows everything.

Comment: I really think you should include the drawRight() implementation in your question so as to be easier helping you.

Comment: Check console for error

Comment: I didn't think it could be neccessary, as it works outside the statement, but sure - I pasted it into my thread now.

Comment: @Mohammad no errors, it loads, but not properly, just like without css and other existing elements dissapear

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try;

`this.id == option1`

I am assuming that your `this.id` is number value and you are comparing it with a string.

PS. I don't know from where this `option1` coming. Please share the source of `option1`.

Comment: `this.id` is string value and so do I compare it.
If statement works perfectly fine, there is no any issue with that, just calling the function. :(

Comment: `$(this).drawRight()` try calling like this.

Comment: `this` in that `if statement` is a class `.leftOption` - doesn't work.